# How to add custom conditional constraints over multiple columns

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

we have a sample reference table like below

```
create table ref_table
(
    id                 bigint       auto_increment primary key,
    ref_id             bigint       not null,
    name               varchar(255) null,
    is_active          bit          not null,
    start_date         datetime     null,
    end_date           datetime     null,
    
)
```

How can we enforce a unique constraint over columns (ref_id, name, is_active) so that at any time there should be on row with is_active::true for given (ref_id, name) and there can be any number of is_active::false rows.

Using mysql8 which has the support for functions as index.

Example scenario:

```
id      ref_id     name     is_active
1       1          name-1   1
2       1          name-1   0
3       1          name-1   0
4       2          name-2   0
5       2          name-2   1
6       2          name-2   0
7       2          name-2   0
```

Comment: Why not use a unique index that uses all 3 columns?

Comment: if we add unique index on all 3 columns, we can only able to add rows with just 2(true, false) values. 

for example 

cols(ref_id, name, is_active)
values((1, sample-name, true),
(1, sample-name, false))

if we try to update/toggle the is_active state, we will get constraint violation error.

requirement is, we should have 1 row with true, and any number of rows with false.

Comment: I understand what you are saying but isn't the name column unique?  I think the problem you are talking about would only happen if the name was duplicated.  If the name is not unique then my idea will not work.

Comment: I have modified the question with some scenario sample data, or expected behaviour. Hope it helps.

Comment: Based on your sample data, the only thing I can think of is to do a query 'WHERE ref_id = ? AND name = ? AND is_active = 1'.  Then use PHP code to check how many records are returned.  If more than 1 then you have dups, write your code to do what you want.

Comment: @CharlesEF this if fine for service layer validation. I'm trying to solve this at db layer, so that it can be applied to many tables.

Comment: Without at least 1 unique column I don't think you can. Maybe someone else will jump in.